# How to determine the position of a car inside an image?

Tags: java, php, c++, algorithm, image-processing

Is it possible to analyse an image and determine the position of a car inside it?
If so, how would you approach this problem?

I'm working with a relatively small data-set (50-100) and most images will look similar to the following examples:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm mostly interested in only detecting vertical coordinates, not the actual shape of the car. For example, this is the area I want to highlight as my final output:
[image]

Comment: Can you also compare towards same images, in absence of the car?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I'm only working with car images. I don't have any version of the same images without the cars in them.

Comment: it is much harder than it seems. Position, angle, color, and perspective greatly vary. But detecting round objects (wheels) can be a good starting point.

Comment: The wheels are actually not round (circles) due to the perspective. Humans are insanely good at this kind of thing. E.g. the whole reason you'd think of the wheels as round is because you already did the perspective correction. On the plus side, if you _do_ have the wheels identified, their shape gives a good estimate for the perspective. And you have a good idea where the rest of the car is, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try OpenCV which has an object detection API. But you would need to "train" it...by supplying it with a large set of images that contained "cars".

- http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/objdetect.html
- http://robocv.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/real-time-object-detection-in-opencv.html
- http://blog.davidjbarnes.com/2010/04/opencv-haartraining-object-detection.html

Look at the 2nd link above and it shows an example of detecting and creating a bounding box around the object....you could use that as a basis for what you want to do.

- http://www.behance.net/gallery/Vehicle-Detection-Tracking-and-Counting/4057777

Various papers:

- http://cbcl.mit.edu/publications/theses/thesis-masters-leung.pdf
- http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi08/cse190-a/reports/scheung.pdf

Various image databases:

- http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/Data/Car/
- http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/Imagedbase.htm
- http://cbcl.mit.edu/software-datasets/CarData.html

Comment: Does OpenCV actually provide a "car is present at angle X" or just a "car is present"? Because that's a big difference.

Comment: See the last link, looks promising.

Comment: Thank you for these links. My working set of images is rather small (only 50-100 images). Most images will look like the ones I've posted in my initial question. I'm also interested in a simpler, more conceptual way of approaching this problem.

Comment: @ukliviu - Have you considered using Amazon Mechturk?  :-)

Comment: @StephenC - that's a very interesting suggestion, although I'm mostly interested in a conceptual/algorithmical solution

Comment: No need to train a new model. He can use latentSVM detector.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your first and second images have two cars in them.

2) If you only have 50-100 images, I can almost guarantee that classifying them all by hand will be faster than writing or adapting an algorithm to recognize cars and deliver coordinates.

3) If you're determined to do this with computer vision, I'd recommend OpenCV. Tutorial here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a [supervised machine learning problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning). You will need to use an API that features learning algorithms as colinsmith suggested or do some research and write on of your own. Python is pretty good for machine learning (it's what I use, personally) and has some nice tools like scikit: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/

Answer (score 0):

You can use openCV latentSVM detector to detect the car and plot a bounding box around it:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/latent_svm.html

No need to train a new model using HaarCascade, as there is already a trained model for cars:

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_extra/tree/master/testdata/cv/latentsvmdetector/models_VOC2007

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest for you to look into HAAR classifiers. Since you mentioned you have a set of 50-100 images, you can use this to build up a training dataset for the classifier and use it to classify your images.

You can also look into SURF and SIFT algorithms for the specified problem.