# A Research project on Object Dtection from a color image using Contourlet Transform

Tags: image-segmentation, object-detection

I want to detect a car using Contourlet Transform from a color image. What are the steps to do it? 
My plan: Image acquisiton-Preprocessing(segmentation)-Contourlet Transform-Feature Extraction-Classification-Featutre Matching-Object Detection 
Am I right? If yes, which step should be started? Which segmentation method is appropriate for my image? Please do help me. I will be grateful to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine the position of a car inside an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385618/how-to-determine-the-position-of-a-car-inside-an-image)

Comment: yeah, You are right. I have to find a car from a color image which contains multiple objects but not only car. I want to detect that which one is car in this image.

Comment: The process of training the model will be nearly the same.

Comment: Could someone ask please which method should be used to extract feature after contourlet transform? I will be grateful to you.